# SQL insert via python looses port 3306

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

After inserting a couple of thousand rows in my mysqldb (xampp) via the python interface (spyder python 3.7), the database is losing the port.

Spyder error-message:

> InterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10048

xampp error-message:

> NetStatTable]  NetStat TCP service stopped. Please restart the control panel. Returned 122

Does anybody have any idea?
thx in advance

Comment: Looks like the DB server crashed. Check its log.

Comment: share us your mysql log

Comment: When I restart the xampp it is working again for a couple of thousands inserts till the next port lost...

Answer (score 0):

this are the mysql logfiles for the last two crashes: (sorry, now Idea how to format properly)

InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint 
LSN=19733761912

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 19733761921; 
transaction id 9577888

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2019-11-12 16:40:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Comment: try to change the port 3306

Comment: there is possibility that you upload your log to www.transferbigfiles.com ...I mean the file log?? and later share it?

Comment: Sorry , I was busy ...I think could be this "Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M"  ..change in your conf the value ...search your my.cnf and look the value : [mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M  ....from 16M to 200MB   later restart services

Comment: sorry for my delay - I've re-installed mysql and changed additionally the way to insert the data - now it is working thx